# Updated = calculated field based on Modified shows 1899 last update

Tags: column

Working with SP 2010 and had to remove the time stamp from modified. Tried at system level - no joy. Used a calculated field (=TEXT(Modified,"mm/dd/yyyy")). This works well but occasionally shows the updated date(yyyy) as 1899. Quite strange. All I have to do to correct is go back to the updated column definition and save. Date returns to normal.

Any ideas?

Comment: a variant of this is one of about half a dozen issues I have on a ticket currently with Microsoft.  I'll update this once I get a resolution from them on it - assuming someone doesn't already have the answer, that is